# jQuery set the same function to different acctions

Tags: jquery, html

i have many actions that should have the same function

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <select id="s1">
            <option>Name</option>
            <option>Year</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <select id="s2">
            <option>Day</option>
            <option>Month</option>
        </select>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and the jQuery calls for that selectors are

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#s1").on('change',function(){
        var value = $("#s1").val();
        alert(value);
    });
    $("#s2").on('change',function(){
        var value = $("#s2").val();
        alert(value);
    });
});
```

look at the calls , they are the same , how can i make them as one call ?
[code](http://jsfiddle.net/WHmGj/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should help

```
$("#s1, #s2").on('change',function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    alert(value);
});
```

if `'#s1`' fires the function so `$(this)` refers to the select tag `'#s1'` so the statement `var value = $(this).val()` will give u the selected option from the select `'#s1'`

and the same thing for the select `'#s2'`
[see this](http://jsfiddle.net/WHmGj/5/)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$("#s1, #s2").on('change', function() {
    var value = this.value; // use native code where possible
    alert(value);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

For what you have you can write like below,

```
$("#s1m, #s2").on('change',function(){
    var value = $(this).val(); //Note using this
    alert(value);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$(function() {
    $("#s1, #s2").on("change", function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        alert(value);
    });
});
```

Use `this` to get the current concerned object.

Answer (score 2):

Try this-->

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#s1, #s2").on('change',function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        alert(value);
    });
});
```